# is AppenderRef level mutually exclusive

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have the following log4j2.xml config

```
   <AsyncRoot level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="fluentd" />
      <AppenderRef ref="log_file" />
      <AppenderRef ref="error" level="warn" />
    </AsyncRoot>
```

Is a log message in level warn/error will get to both error appender and log_file/fluentd?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I looked at the docs but couldn't find a definite answer. I suspect it was changed between log4j versions?

Answer (score 1):

Testing it with log4j 2.19. If the message is at `warn` level then all appenders will get it.

Comment: Yes, if the message is more specific than `INFO`, all appender refs are used. Unless they filter the message (as the appender "error" does), it will end up in all three logs.